# Mean Absolute Deviation and data preprocessing

Tags: self-study, outliers, data-preprocessing, mad

Assume we have data points $x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}, x_{n+1}$. Next, based on Mean Absolute Deviation (MAD) we aim to decide if the last point $x_{n+1}$ is outlier or not.

First, let us compute the MAD:
$$
MAD = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i} - m|}{n},
$$
where $m = median(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n})$.

Then, we check if $|x_{n+1} - m|$ is greater than $q*MAD$, where $q$ is some coefficient.

The question: should we consider the point under consideration, $x_{n+1}$, in the computation of MAD and (or) median or we must exclude it like in the approach described above?